# Why are do non-ToggleButton children of ToggleButtonGroup trigger React warning recognizing "fullWidth"?

Tags: material-ui, slider

I'm using MUI to place ToggleButtons, which after being clicked, enable Sliders to increase/decrease a number.

Here's the error (to be clear, I do not define fullWidth anywhere):
*Warning: React does not recognize the `fullWidth` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `fullwidth` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.*

My code below seems to me to be a decent solution, except for the warning. It slows down loading, so I'd like to figure out the root cause and deal with it.

```
      <ToggleButtonGroup
      color="primary"
      value={alignment}
      aria-label="Platform"
    >
      {Object.entries(items).map(([category, item]) => (
        <Box key={category}>
          <ToggleButton
            value={category}
            onClick={() => handleButtonClick(category)}
          >
            {category}
          </ToggleButton>
          <Slider
            getAriaValueText={valuetext}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            step={1}
            marks
            min={0}
            max={5}
            disabled={!item.enabled}
            value={item.value}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => handleSliderChange(newValue, category)}
          />
        </Box>
      ))}
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Alternatively, if there is a better way to approach the problem, I'd be grateful for suggestions.  I figure I'm misusing the ToggleButtonGroup, but don't know another way of doing it without much more complicated state or formatting.

I tried putting Slider inside each ToggleButton, which removed the warning but complicated state greatly as both pressing the togglebutton and adjusting the slider can impact the same number.

I also tried adding a second iteration after the ToggleButtonGroup to place the Sliders, but it seems challenging to line each Slider perfectly under its associated ToggleButton.